# Animating height using Framer Motion not working in React

Tags: reactjs, animation, height, framer-motion

So, I have been trying to use Framer Motion for my React project. I basically want to animate the height from 0 to "auto", when the div gets rendered.
I tried the below code, but the height is not getting animated

```
<motion.div
  initial={{ height: 0 }}
  animate={{ height: "auto" }}
  transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
  key={searchQuery?.length}
>
```

When I **replaced height with width, the animation works fine**, but can't figure out why the height is not getting animated. And I was unable to find any proper documentation regarding this.

Here is the [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-water-gzichf?file=/src/App.js) for demo.

Comment: What happens when you set the height to auto without framer motion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fixed versinn](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wood-fpjuwy?file=/src/App.js)

#### What was wrong?

Your conditional rendering logic was in the wrong place, `AnimatePresence` works only if its direct child disappears.

`exit` prop was missing

`key` prop has to be stable, it can't be the length of the string

`overflow: hidden` have to be added so the children are invisible

Final code:

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder={"Enter Keyword"}
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <AnimatePresence>
          {searchQuery?.length >= 1 && (
            <motion.div
              style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
              initial={{ height: 0 }}
              animate={{ height: "auto" }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
              exit={{ height: 0 }}
              key={"container"}
            >
              {dataList?.map((listItem) => (
                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "1rem",
                    color: "#E090EE",
                    borderBottom: "1px solid #E1E1E1",
                  }}
                >
                  {listItem.activity_title}
                </div>
              ))}
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped. Can you please also tell me, why is `overflow: hidden` required? It was not required when I was trying to animate height.